# Missing Ether from Bitstamp to Jaxx Wallet

Tags: ether

Need some help please. I sent two transactions of ether to my friends ether wallet.

1. From coinbase .8 eth
2. From bitstamp 1 ether

The coinbase ether has shown up in his wallet; however, the bitstamp 1 ether has not shown up.

I went to ether scan to check his wallet and find where the missing ether is. It looks like to me it is sitting in the "internal transactions"

I assume this because of the timestamps. I sent the bitstamp transfer first and the coinbase transfer second. They are both two minutes apart.

[Here is the link](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe5cfd9afb137413c7b57b9c737729308af157809#internaltx) on Ether scan .

Can someone please help and tell me what is going on with the 1 ETH? Will it be credited to my friends wallet? What should I do?

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 1):

If it's sitting in Internal Transactions, it has already been credited.

Looking at the times, the 1 ETH was credited to his wallet on 11 october 2017 at 12:07:10 UTC in this transaction:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd95a95dcfb43778e3bbaf7abff1071e8be36d9a4748c4590b244a9273b163bd4

Then, about 3 hours later, he sent 3.3 ETH away to another address:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf31bebdb65c64a18286a520b5339d611ad994e8d505b486f2832e1613c7a9d6e

I added and subtracted all the transactions, and this is correct. It most certainly has already been credited to his account, he just sent it somewhere else 3 hours after receiving it.

Comment: jesse he is saying that it is not showing up in his jaxx wallet and even sent me a screenshot of the wallet....what can be done? is he simply not adding correclty? from the screenshot i can see that it is not there...